# I have a js. script that reads a json file, and I need to find the equivalent to read a .csv file

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I'm reading the similar JSON file in JavaScript

```
<script type="application/json" id="mis">
   {"nodes":
     [{"id":"Banana and Coffee","group":1,"weighted_degree":7269},
      {"id":"Agriculture","group":1,"weighted_degree":12827}],
     "links":
     [{"source":11,"target":23,"value":12},
      {"source":11,"target":6,"value":12}]}
```

and I'm using the following script:

```
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
    graph = JSON.parse(mis);
```

Now, I have two separated CSV files (see below) with the same information. And I need to find a script that could a similar job as it's done with the JSON file.

nodes.csv

```
id, group, weighted_degree
Banana and Coffee, 1, 7269  
Agriculture, 1, 12827
```

links.csv

```
source, target, value
11, 23, 12
11, 6, 12
```

Comment: http://papaparse.com/

Comment: did you try googling for "javascript csv parser"

Answer (score 1):

The comment that suggests googling on javascript csv parser is not wrong. There are a number of ways to approach this; the easiest is to use an existing library. The library itself depends on the your development environment. Are you building a node app? If so, check out any number of csv parsers available as npm packages. If you are reading from an external file and are a glutton for punishment, you could use node's built-in file handling module, fs, to buffer and parse the stream yourself. That's the sort of thing you tend to do once, for the learning experience, and thereafter take joy in others' kind efforts to build and package this sort of solution.

In any case, this is a problem that has been solved many times. Search the internet, Luke. You will find those droids.